# how @variable@ works

Tags: sql-server, xml, variables

This is a question and I am after an explanation. I mean this sql already works fine.. I am trying to understand an sql logic which I have it in a system. Maybe a custom one because I could not find a sample on the internet. It does not matter what this sql does, I just like to know how @businessdate@ and @locid@ interpreted.

- By the way, this sql as you see below in an xml file.
- no data source defined.

If these information is not enough please let me know.

```
<query name="allItems" type="sql" result-type="single-row" datasource="">
    <raw-sql>
    SELECT  salesCount, salesTotal, discountTotal
    FROM    menu_item_daily LEFT OUTER JOIN menu_item
    ON menu_item_daily.menuItemID = menu_item.menuItemID
    WHERE  menu_item_daily.orgId @orgId@ AND
        menu_item_daily.businessDate @businessdate@ AND
        menu_item_daily.locationID @locid@
     </raw-sql>
</query>
```

Comment: How are you using this XML?

Comment: Lol where did you found this xml snippet. What is the url of the website where you saw this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. The SQL you have isn't valid as it is because there are no operators to compare the variables to the columns. Are you asking how the variables are populated with values; why they have @ at both beginning and end (which is [allowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx), by the way); how the SQL is turned into something that can be executed; or something else?